# Why stationary armature is preferred for commercial use

Tags: generator, electricity, electric-machine

While reading a book on electrical machines, I found a point that says that for power generation, a stationary armature is the preferred type.
If in any generator, there must be moving parts, why is the choice of stationary armature preferred.

Comment: Avoids brushes, slip-rings, or similar sliding contacts carrying current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because large currents need sizable conductors and brushes wear.

So fixed connections are easier and only a permanent magnet or a small excitation current needs to be rotated.